# Can't Start SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm making a website for a school project. Downloaded Visual Studio 2010 (The version we have in school) and now I'm trying to run my website on it.
The SQL won't connect. I tried everything I knew, nothing works.
When attempting to connect in SQL Server Management Studio it gives me 'Login failed' for my user. By the way I'm trying windows authentication Tried looking at SQL error logs and there weren't any!

I'm getting very frustrated, every answer I saw online referred to real websites and terms I don't understand. I'm just trying to make my database work! Please, please help.

Don't know what to do.

EDIT: Okay found the logs!! It was in a folder a bit different then mentioned.
I think this is the issue:
EDIT: Tried a few steps suggested. The server is now (I think) in single user mode.
Still can't log in but different issue - Here's the log.

```
2013-05-26 19:14:03.97 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) 
    Jun 28 2012 08:36:30 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

2013-05-26 19:14:03.97 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2013-05-26 19:14:03.97 Server      All rights reserved.
2013-05-26 19:14:03.97 Server      Server process ID is 2968.
2013-05-26 19:14:03.97 Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.
2013-05-26 19:14:03.97 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2013-05-26 19:14:03.97 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 4068 at 26/05/2013 19:11:31 (local) 26/05/2013 16:11:31 (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2013-05-26 19:14:03.97 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
     -m
2013-05-26 19:14:03.99 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-05-26 19:14:03.99 Server      Detected 4 CPUs. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.00 Server      Perfmon counters for resource governor pools and groups failed to initialize and are disabled.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.00 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.01 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0 Active CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.02 Server      Database Mirroring Transport is disabled in the endpoint configuration.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.02 spid6s      Warning ******************
2013-05-26 19:14:04.02 spid6s      SQL Server started in single-user mode. This an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.02 spid6s      Starting up database 'master'.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.10 spid6s      Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.14 spid6s      FILESTREAM: effective level = 0, configured level = 0, file system access share name = 'SQLEXPRESS'.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.15 spid6s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2013-05-26 19:14:04.15 spid6s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.19 spid6s      The resource database build version is 10.50.4000. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.28 spid9s      Starting up database 'model'.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.28 spid6s      Server name is 'NETA\SQLEXPRESS'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.28 spid6s      Informational: No full-text supported languages found.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.28 spid6s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.39 Server      A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.39 Server      Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQLEXPRESS ].
2013-05-26 19:14:04.39 Server      Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\sql\query ].
2013-05-26 19:14:04.39 Server      Dedicated administrator connection support was not started because it is disabled on this edition of SQL Server. If you want to use a dedicated administrator connection, restart SQL Server using the trace flag 7806. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.39 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Error: 0x54b, state: 3. Failure to register an SPN may cause integrated authentication to fall back to NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.39 Server      SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.50 spid9s      Clearing tempdb database.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.74 spid9s      Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2013-05-26 19:14:04.80 spid6s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2013-05-26 19:14:14.60 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 11.
2013-05-26 19:14:14.60 Logon       Login failed for user 'Neta\Neta'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Yes, I'm the administrator

Comment: Please post the _exact_ error you get. Also, to double-check, by `administrator` you refer to SQL Server permissions, not Windows ones?

Comment: Now I lost you.. If it's not set by default I think not.

Comment: Did you set up database engine to use Windows Authentication (default)? Do you run Management Studio as the user that made SQL Server installation? Also you may wish to try these steps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/07/12/disaster-recovery-what-to-do-when-the-sa-account-password-is-lost-in-sql-server-2005.aspx

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure I did. I only have one user on this PC...

Comment: Er, logs say `Authentication mode is MIXED`. That's not default if memory serves me well. So, you likely provided password for `sa` user during setup. Do you remember it? If yes, then try to login as `sa` user. Still, once your server is in single-user mode, you're one step from granting your `Neta\Neta` user `sysadmin` rights. Steps're in the link I posted before.

Comment: YES!!!!! Managed to login with sa. Now I need to give Neta\Neta administrative rights?

Comment: Great to know that you managed to solve it. The best thing to do now is to post the resolution receipt as your own answer -- this shall help people who stumble upon the same problem in the future. PS. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 2):

maybe your sql server services is not started. try this...

go to: **control panel -> administrative Tools -> services**

check that these services are started :

1. SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (MSSQLSERVER)
2. SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
3. SQL Server Integration Services 10.0
4. SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)
5. SQL Server VSS Writer

```
after check that all, launch SQL Server Management Studio .

you may connect to your server now with click on connect button:
(server type: database engine, server name:. and authentication:windows authentication)

in object explorer on left side by default you should see your server, if not, try click on "connect object explorer" then click on connect button.
```

I'm sorry for horrible delay, because i see your comment now. I just think, maybe you have another program that uses your ms sql server port. for example ms sql server use port 80 and another program/server like apache use same port . 
if each began start earlier on windows logon/startup , 1st program takes that port so don't allow other to use that port.
so !? you must check 80 port is not use by another program if your problem is still remaining.

Comment: Actually, I only have the SQL Server and SQL Server VSS Writer.
But I have 3 more with different names so I think those are the missing 3.
My problem is that I can't connect with SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: you know ... I think when you have multiple instances on your system as ms SQL server instance ... you need more careful when you have enter your server name. it was better, if you have visual studio on your system and try to retrieve server names so you could make sure that your server name is correctly entered or not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after you've installed Microsoft SQL server, you need to reboot your PC then make sure it is correctly added into Windows Services. Try to run "services.msc" and locate Microsoft SQL Server service, check status and if it's sopped -> start it.

Comment: Tried it, still same result.

Answer (score 1):

try using [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) using an [sql connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) to connect to sql. Generally works better than other methods.